# How do I add a column to dataframe on condition that certain observations in my dataframe contain a target word in Python?

Tags: python, data-mining, dataset

Here's what my data frame look like:

```
Number  Age      Famous_for                            
1       35       "businessman chairman of IBM (1973–1981)"
2       42       "musician (House of Freaks Gutterball)"
3       87       "baseball player (Oakland Athletics)"
```

I want to create additional column that will contain a dummy variable whether or not person was involved with entertaining business. Something like that:

```
Number..Age..................Famous_for.....................Entertaining                            
1.......35.......businessman chairman of IBM (1973–1981)........0              
2.......42.......musician (House of Freaks Gutterball)..........1                
3.......87.......baseball player (Oakland Athletics)............0
```

How do I create a column based on the certain words in the famous for column (such as "musician", "club", "actor" and etc)?
I tried the following:

```
df['entertaining'] = np.where(df['famous_for']>="musician", 1, 0)
```

but it wouldn't work.
How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.contains on the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age' : pd.Series([35,42,87], index=[1,2,3]),
        'Famous_for': pd.Series(['businessman chairman of IBM (1973–1981)',
                                 'musician (House of Freaks Gutterball)',
                                 'baseball player (Oakland Athletics)'], 
        index=[1,2,3])
        })

df['entertaining'] = df['Famous_for'].str.contains('musician')
print (df)

   Age                               Famous_for entertaining
1   35  businessman chairman of IBM (1973–1981)        False
2   42    musician (House of Freaks Gutterball)         True
3   87      baseball player (Oakland Athletics)        False
```

Note that str.contains also accepts a regular expression, so if you wish to search for various words you might use

```
df['entertaining'] = df['Famous_for'].str.contains('musician|businessman')
```

Comment: I'd do it this way: `words = ['musician','club','actor']; df['entertaining'] = df['Famous_for'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(words)).astype(np.int8)`